# Rotate multiple classes through multiple elements on the DOM

Tags: jquery

As I click the button the classes would rotate up or down through each div. so far all I can do is rotate the classes, but it only rotates the classes for the same div.

```js
 

var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];  // the different classes to rotate through each div




$('div').each(function() {     // the div needs to rotate classes over and over
    var i = 0;
    
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('div').removeClass( classes[ i ] );
        i = ++i % classes.length;            
        $('div').addClass( classes[ i ] );
    });
});
```

```css
div { color:white; margin: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.a {
    background-color: blue;
}

.b {
    background-color: red;
}

.c {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>  //class change on click to b, than c, back to a..
<div class="b"></div>  //this change to c than a than b ..
<div class="c"></div> // basically these classes always rotate

<button>
rotate
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First initialize variable outside the body and declare inside
   document ready section so it will not reinitialize again.
2. Shift the array then Add/Remove Class.

```js
var  classes ;
$(document).ready(function() {
 classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
});

   
    $('button').click(function() {
    debugger;
    var i = 0;
     var remove = classes.shift();
      classes.push(remove)
    $('div').each(function(key) { 
   
    $(this).removeClass()
    
    $(this).addClass(classes[i]);
      i++;
      
    });
});
```

```css
div { color:white; margin: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.a {
    background-color: blue;
}

.b {
    background-color: red;
}

.c {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>  //class change on click to b, than c, back to a..
<div class="b"></div>  //this change to c than a than b ..
<div class="c"></div> // basically these classes always rotate

<button>
rotate
</button>
```